# if_exist macros in LaTeX 3: what are they doing if they do not check the type of things they are supposed to check?

Tags: macros, expl3, latex3, programming

In the documentation of [interface3](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf), for several macros with the pattern `xxxx_if_exist` for xxxx being `bool`, `str`, `seq` and many others the following appear:

> ```
> Tests whether the <boolean> is currently defined. 
> This does not check that the <boolean> really is a boolean variable.
>
> Tests whether the <str var> is currently defined. 
> This does not check that the <str var> really is a string.
>
> Tests whether the <seq var> is currently defined. 
> This does not check that the <seq var> really is a sequence variable.
> ```

**Question:** If they are not checking for the type of the input parameter then, how do they differ from each other? How do they differ from `\cs_if_exist`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They don't differ at all from `\cs_if_exist:N(TF)`, because they *are* exactly the same: in `expl3-code.tex` we see (line numbers for reference)

```
   3503 \prg_new_eq_conditional:NNn \tl_if_exist:N \cs_if_exist:N { TF , T , F , p }

   4846 \prg_new_eq_conditional:NNn \str_if_exist:N \tl_if_exist:N
   4847   { p , T , F , TF }

   5617 \prg_new_eq_conditional:NNn \seq_if_exist:N \cs_if_exist:N
   5618   { TF , T , F , p }

   6427 \prg_new_eq_conditional:NNn \int_if_exist:N \cs_if_exist:N
   6428   { TF , T , F , p }

   7136 \prg_new_eq_conditional:NNn \flag_if_exist:N \cs_if_exist:N
   7137   { TF , T , F , p }

   7287 \prg_new_eq_conditional:NNn \bool_if_exist:N \cs_if_exist:N
   7288   { TF , T , F , p }

   8129 \prg_new_eq_conditional:NNn \clist_if_exist:N \cs_if_exist:N
   8130   { TF , T , F , p }

  10053 \prg_new_eq_conditional:NNn \prop_if_exist:N \cs_if_exist:N
  10054   { TF , T , F , p }

  12842 \prg_new_eq_conditional:NNn \dim_if_exist:N \cs_if_exist:N
  12843   { TF , T , F , p }

  13269 \prg_new_eq_conditional:NNn \skip_if_exist:N \cs_if_exist:N
  13270   { TF , T , F , p }

  13362 \prg_new_eq_conditional:NNn \muskip_if_exist:N \cs_if_exist:N
  13363   { TF , T , F , p }

  17463 \prg_new_eq_conditional:NNn \fp_if_exist:N \cs_if_exist:N { TF , T , F , p }

  22075 \prg_new_eq_conditional:NNn
  22076   \bitset_if_exist:N \str_if_exist:N { p , T , F , TF }

  22491 \prg_new_eq_conditional:NNn \cctab_if_exist:N \cs_if_exist:N
  22492   { TF , T , F , p }

  29177 \prg_new_eq_conditional:NNn \box_if_exist:N \cs_if_exist:N
  29178   { TF , T , F , p }
```

What's their purpose? Well, nothing excludes that in the future some of these functions can *actually* test that the variable has the appropriate type, which in some cases might be possible (not that I think it will be done, to be honest).

Their purpose is *good programming*. A `tl` variable is *not* a `cs`, at least from a higher level point of view (at the lowest level, both are macros). Providing the different conditionals helps in keeping them separate.

Please, use them, and not the generic `\cs_if_exist:N(TF)`.

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: Their definitions currently don't differ at all. The difference lies in semantics.

## An attempt at a slightly longer answer:

Note that at least with conventional macro names this is a no-issue, there shouldn't ever be a macro named like an integer variable, for instance, that's defined but not actually an integer. So this is a clear case of balancing performance against complete correctness of the test, and here performance clearly wins; there is a reason why we so strongly advocate for using the naming conventions.